# Choosing prior distribution in logit model

Tags: error-handling, winbugs

I am conducting a logit regression analysis in winbugs from R. I have to force all of the coefficients of this model to be positive. Therefore, I used uniform priors for all of the coefficients, but winbugs is not happy with that: it generates a silly error windows. When I used `dnorm(0.0,1.0E-4))` as prior for all the coefficients, the problem was solved. What can be done to obtain positive betas in this model given below?

```
model
{
for (i in 1:m) {
 # Linear regression on logit
 logit(p[i]) <- beta.concern2*DCEconcern2[i] + beta.concern3*DCEconcern3[i] +     beta.concern4*DCEconcern4[i] + beta.concern5*DCEconcern5[i] +
beta.breath2*DCEbreath2[i] + beta.breath3*DCEbreath3[i] + beta.breath4*DCEbreath4[i] + beta.breath5*DCEbreath5[i] + 
beta.weath2*DCEweath2[i] +beta.weath3*DCEweath3[i] +beta.weath4*DCEweath4[i] +beta.weath5*DCEweath5[i] +
beta.sleep2*DCEsleep2[i] +beta.sleep3*DCEsleep3[i] +beta.sleep4*DCEsleep4[i] +beta.sleep5*DCEsleep5[i] +
beta.act2*DCEact2[i] +beta.act3*DCEact3[i] +beta.act4*DCEact4[i]     +beta.act5*DCEact5[i]


y2[i] ~ dbern(p[i])
}
beta.concern2 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.concern3 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.concern4 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.concern5 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.breath2 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.breath3 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.breath4 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.breath5 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.weath2 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.weath3 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.weath4 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.weath5 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.sleep2 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.sleep3 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.sleep4 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.sleep5 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.act2 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.act3 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.act4 ~ dunif(0,100)
beta.act5 ~ dunif(0,100)
}
```

Comment: Whoever has the permission please migrate this to stats.se (I flagged it)..

Answer (score 1):

Try

dnorm(0, 1.0E-8)I(0, 1.0E8)

Notice the 1.0 instead of the 10, which was causing the "expected right parenthesis" error.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would prefer half flat normal, i.e. something like

```
dnorm(0, 1.0E-8)I(0, 1.0E8)
```

Give it a shot.

EDIT: the added `I(a, b)` just limits the distribution to the interval from `a` to `b`.

Comment: I used `beta.concern2 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-8)I(0, 10E8)` for all of the betas, but another error and a window came up in winbugs. The window shows the model which I store in a .txt file and error says `display(log)
check(C:/Users/Desktop/Dissertation2/Bayesian/winbugslogit.txt)
expected right parenthesis
data(C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpwjMuDE/data.txt)`
Any idea?

Comment: @EDo This seems unrelated to the prior selection, at the first sight, however might be, as winbugs errors are absolutely undecipherable... I would try jags, it gives more comprehensible error messages.

Comment: when I use normal priors for the betas, the code perfectly works. Therefore, I think it must be the prior distribution, but not %100 sure of course. Also, can you please briefly explain what `dnorm(0, 1.0E-8)I(0, 10E8)` does. Finally, does jags use the same language as Winbugs and do what winbugs does?

Comment: @Edo, see my edit. And yes, you can run the same model in jags. There are some differences but this model is pretty basic.